# Adjust Title Helper in Ruby on Rails Tutorial 3.2 to deal with & properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, railstutorial.org

I am using the title helper from the 3.2 edition of the Ruby on Rails Tutorial by Michael Hartl and just realized a snag with the & character showing up in the title as &Amp; instead.

The relevant snippet of code is here [Official Sample App 2nd Edition](https://github.com/railstutorial/sample_app_2nd_ed/blob/master/app/helpers/application_helper.rb)

---

**The problem.** I have a School model and am using the School name on the Show view as follows:

```
<% provide(:title, @school.name) %>
```

---

**If my School has a & in the name, it is being replaced with &Amp;** in the browser title.

---

Ryan Bates Railscasts site has a similiar title helper that solves this issue [this way](https://github.com/ryanb/railscasts/blob/master/app/helpers/layout_helper.rb)
but it is using **content_for** instead of **provide**.

---

Trying to adjust the Rails Tutorial helper, but having trouble getting it work properly. Works great expect for this issue.

Comment: That RailsCast is a little dated. `content_for` needs to be replaced with `provide` for compatibility with the Rails asset pipeline.

Comment: I liked the explanation you gave for using provide, so that is why I went with your option. The answer below seems to have helped me out. Either way I appreciate your Tutorial and detailed explanations. Don't know why StackOverflow is blocking my attempt to tag as tutorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the page_title helper and add `html_safe` to the output strings so does not convert the ampersands and leaves them intact

```
def full_title(page_title)
  base_title = "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"
  if page_title.empty?
    base_title.html_safe
  else
    "#{base_title} | #{page_title}".html_safe
  end
end
```